# Mirth connect javascript reader

Tags: javascript, mirth

I am using mirth connect 3.0.3 on windows.my requirement is I have a text file in D drive with some name and id as the text I need to pick that file using mirth javascript reader and insert into the database can u please help me to pick the file using javascript reader.

I tried it by using java code and converting that into to .jar file and placed it in the custom-lib folder in mirth connect and importing that in a script but I want to do it without `.jar` file

I am getting stuck in importing the packages can you help me to pick the file using javascript reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take two aproaches:

1. Use a File Reader source insted of JavaScript Reader source, then modify the transformer adding a new step in which insert your file's content into your database.
2. Use the [FileUtil.read](http://javadocs.mirthcorp.com/connect/3.1.0/user-api/com/mirth/connect/server/userutil/FileUtil.html#read(java.lang.String)) method to read file content inside your Javascript Reader source:

```
    var fileData = FileUtil.read('D:\my_awesome_folder\data.txt');

    //Do something with fileData
```